# Problem receiving Json response with responseType set to Json in Jquery AjaxUploader

Tags: .net, jquery, ajax, uploader

I am using jquery ajaxuploader in my asp.net website.When I set `responseType: 'json'` in 'AjaxUpload' the `onComplete` is not getting executed.In the firebug I am able to see the json response as `{"Error":null,"Success":true}` along with the entire page markup to which the 'AjaxUpload' has made the request.

I am having trouble understanding why the 'onComplete' is not being hit with 'responseType' set to 'json' and how can I get only the 'json' response without the entire page markup .

Could someone please help.

**Update**:I think the reason behind 'onComplete' not getting executed is because the browser is receiving json response along with the entire page markup(which is not json).If it is so how can I send only json response excluding the page markup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized where am I going wrong.I was actually sending a request to .aspx page from AjaxUpload which is the reason why i was getting the entire page markup along with the json response.I have updated AjaxUpload method to send the request to .ashx page and its working fine now.